# How to apply a function along an axis which can modify the length of samples?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a batch of variable-length sequences and three channels. So `x` has the shape `(None, None, 3)` or `[batch_size, sample_length, channel]` with `batch_size` and `sample_length` being dynamic dimensions.

In one of my steps I want to apply a function `f` to *each* of the samples in `x`. The problem with `f`: The `sample_length` can change.

As I tried to run:

```
new_x = tf.map_fn(lambda sample: f(sample), x)
```

I got this error:

```
Could not write to TensorArray index 2 because the value shape is 
[10,257] which is incompatible with the TensorArray's inferred 
element shape: [11,257] (consider setting infer_shape=False).
```

which makes sense since, as stated, `f` may modify `sample_length`.

The question here is how could I make something like this work? Since each sample has a variable length to begin with, I am sure this must somehow be possible but I don't know how I could achieve that.

Any ideas?

---

#### Environment

```
$ pip freeze | grep tensorflow-gpu
tensorflow-gpu==1.12.0
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to get as a result? The only way to achieve exactly this would be with a [ragged tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor), which is not the most comfortable thing to use... Otherwise, you would have to have an array with padding in the sequences, and keep and additional mask or array of sequence lengths.

Comment: @jdehesa Essentially, I want to get `new_x` in terms of `f()`. The result is a tensor with the same dimensionality `[batch_size, sample_length, channel]` but for each example the `sample_length` may or changed. `x` (and therefore `new_x`) is just a batch of examples. I never used ragged tensors. I will take a look at it. I can see the padding option as well but that's not too much fun either - mainly because the length changes randomly (depending on a random variable).

Comment: I just noticed that v1.12 does not have a `tf.ragged` module.